# Unittest the pytorch forward function

Tags: python, pytorch, vgg-net

I want to unittest the overridden forward function of my Network modell in Pytorch. So I loaded my model (pretrained from Zoo) with the setUp method, loaded a seed and created some random batch. In my method testForward I tested the result of forward against shape and numel, but I also want to check a specific value which a apears to be 0. I wasn't shure about that so checked my params in setUp also, which appears not to be 0.

```py
import unittest
import torch
from SemanticSegmentation.models.fcn8 import FCN8


class TestFCN8(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.model = FCN8(8, pretrained=True)
        torch.manual_seed(0)
        self.x = torch.rand((4, 3, 45, 45))
        for param in self.model.parameters():
            print(param.data)

    def testForward(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.model.forward(self.x).shape.numel(), 64800)
        self.assertEqual(str(self.model.forward(self.x).shape), 'torch.Size([4, 8, 45, 45])')
        print(self.model.named_parameters)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

So my Question is: the sahpe of the forward return tensor is what I expect but why is this tensor completly zero? I expected at least a few values.

The imported modell is based on an VGG16 network with upscoring the after ConvLayer 4 , 8 and 16. If needed I could also present the modell code.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after tinkering around and debugging the forward function I came to following explanation:

## Some Information about the architecture

If you do classes from Andrew Ng or others you learn not to initialize the weights to the same value, as example "0". This is what the writers of the original Paper of FCNs do and they say, because it doesn't change the performance or didn't yield to faster convergence ([FCN-Paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4038)).

## My Solution

So for testing purpose I initlize in the testing module to seeded random values, which I can test against:

```py
import unittest
import torch
from SemanticSegmentation.models.fcn8 import FCN8


class TestFCN8(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.model = FCN8(8, pretrained=True)
        torch.manual_seed(0)
        # instead of zero init for score tensors use random init
        self.model.score_fr[6].weight.data.random_()
        self.model.score_fr[6].bias.data.random_()
        self.model.score_pool3.weight.data.random_()
        self.model.score_pool3.bias.data.random_()
        self.model.score_pool4.weight.data.random_()
        self.model.score_pool4.bias.data.random_()
        self.x = torch.rand((4, 3, 45, 45))

    def testForward(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            self.model.forward(self.x).shape.numel(), 64800)
        self.assertEqual(
            list(self.model.forward(self.x).shape), [4, 8, 45, 45])
        self.assertEqual(
            float(self.model.forward(self.x)[3][4][44][4]), 2277257216.0))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```